# How can I read data from controls on window in a different application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, winapi

I have to write an application that observes another application and extracts information from the window. What is the best way to access windows from other applications and get data from their controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to P/Invoke the [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) and [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx) functions to retrieve a handle to the other application's parent window and child controls.

Then you will need to use something like [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520.aspx) to access the text for a particular control.

Visit [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) for the definitions you'll need to call these functions from C#.

Be warned that this is not a completely straightforward pursuit. You should stop to consider whether you really have a good reason for wanting to do this, and if your goal couldn't be achieved in a simpler way.

Comment: an alternative would be doing a screenshot and transform the text via ocr or something like this in strings.... but im not sure if this is much better

Comment: @skelle: I hope that is a joke!

Comment: @skelle: No, that definitely wouldn't be better... What I suggested is the customary way that this is done, I'm just warning you that it's not as straightforward as the rest of the code you might write in a typical C# application. The question was more of, why do you need to read data from another application's controls? Is there a way to integrate the applications so that they *share* data, rather than forcefully extracting it.

Comment: nope i cannot integrate this application... i hav to start the other application and observe its outputs so i think i hav to talk this way right?

Comment: @skelle: Yes. If you're starting the other application from within your application, you can use `Process.Start` and have part of the work already done for you. In particular, you don't have to use the `FindWindow` function to retrieve the handle to the other application's main window because you can use `Process.MainWindowHandle` instead. See [this post](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=32) for details. You'll still need to enumerate the child controls, though.

Comment: Be aware that some controls are harder to get at than others. In particular text from list views can't be obtained this way since the Windows messages involved don't marshall the data across the process boundary - you have to do that yourself.

Comment: ok thanks for the help... i will start experimenting with this :)

Comment: @skelle, @David: Yeah, that's a good point. the ListView and TreeView controls are stereotypically a pain in the behind. See [my answer here on the ListView control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857602/get-listview-items-from-other-windows/4857746#4857746) for details on accessing those items from another C# application.

Comment: how do i acces the controls when i hav the handle? alle the example just show how to send messages to the window :/

Comment: @skelle: Depends on what specifically that you want to *access*. Once you have the handle, you can use any of the Windows API functions to interact with the control. You just pass in the window handle as the first argument. But since you're working in C#, you'll have to find the P/Invoke definition for that function and copy it into your code first. In my answer, I suggested using the `GetWindowText` to get the text displayed by a particular control. This will return the caption of a button or label, for example. I can't tell you much more without knowing what you want to get from the control.

Comment: @Cody Gray it seems you are very familiar with this topic... is there a way i might can contact you? (skype, jabber mail whatever) maybe you hav a couple if minutes to help me

Comment: @skelle: I don't really have any of those services. The amount of time I spend "talking" online is pretty much limited to Stack Overflow. If you have any more questions that are *directly* related, you can edit this question to include an update. I'll be happy to respond if I know the answer. If you have a slightly different issue, it might be worth posting a new question to get some fresh eyes.

Comment: Yeah my actually question how i should continue when i hav the MainWindowHandle...how do i access different controls in the window!?

Comment: @skelle: To get the handles for child controls, you need to use [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx), which is part of the native Windows API. It's not exposed directly by the .NET Framework, so you'll need to P/Invoke to use it. You'll find the definition you need to paste into your project to call that function [here on pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html). There's even sample code that shows you how to use it.