# pinvoke SysListView Get Context Menu

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to get the context-menu (*right*-click) from a Item in a **[SysListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**..

I know there is a function in user32.dll [GetMenu](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetMenu.html) and [GetMenuItemCount](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetMenuItemCount.html) etc..

But how can I get the **Handle** of the Item in the SysListView..

Next question would be, how can i "*click*" an Item from the Menu?

Comment: Where does that SysListView class come from?

Comment: You probably want to look at this for starters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857602/get-listview-items-from-other-windows as it shows you how to a handle to the list view item. Are you completely sure that the menu is on the item, rather than the list view itself? All of the references that i can see refer to the menu being on the list. (BTW from the look of that first post you might want to up your bounty!)

Comment: @SimonMourier `SysListView` is the Windows list view component. It's provided by comctl32.

Comment: It's far from clear what you are actually doing here. I think your bounty is wasted unless you improve your question. If your question was clear, there'd be no need for a bounty. I suspect that the list view control is in a different process. Is that right? In any case, list view control's don't come with a context menu. That's supplied by the app that hosts the control. So, again could you make it clear what you want. Is what you want to automate an action from explorer.exe, the Windows shell?

Comment: How to you create/define that SysListView class? If you reference ComCtl32.ocx, it will create a ListViewClass (and an IListView interface). The link you added to SysListView is *not* from ComCtl32, it's the standard Windows control.

Comment: I access the List in another Process. As I said in my Question, if I right-click on an Item in the List, I'll get a menu. And I want to get this menu and want to click an Option from it.
@TheMouthofaCow I already can read the Values from this List.

Comment: @RaphaelH: Do you show the context menu yourself by sending a message to the listview (or similar)? Or are you hijacking a context menu that has been opened by the user? And do you want to get the handle of the item in the list view or the handle of the context menu?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It's not my program, so I do not show any menu. I'd like to access it and "fake" a click on an option from this menu.

Comment: @RaphaelH: And how does this menu come to life? A context menu normally isn't shown always - something triggers it. What or who is that trigger?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth As I already said in my question "I'm trying to get the context-menu (right-click)", I have to right-click on an item in the syslistview.

Comment: If you are using it from a different process to access the UI elements, then the only way is to look at the accessibility interface. but, I am afraid that accessibility interface only allows to get the info from the UI elements, not actually manipulating them.

Comment: What means manipulating? I do not want to change anything. I only want to get the Menu Entries and click one.

Answer (score 0):

try first to get handle to the main window that holds the listview, after that its easy find what you want
you will need Microsoft spy++ to find exactly where the listview inside the program window