# getting listview item from other windows application always return empty string

Tags: c#

I'm making winform application which needs to get content of a listview from other windows application which has several tabs, each tab contains a listview, like Windows Task Manager.

I was following this Q&A [Get ListView items from other windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857602/get-listview-items-from-other-windows) and this guide [Crossing the process boundry with .NET](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21665455/win32-api-ListView-contents.html).
Unluckily, I'm really a newbie in win32api. I always get empty string returned from local buffer.

Below is my code so far.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
        private const int LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = LVM_FIRST + 4;
        private const int LVM_GETITEM = LVM_FIRST + 75;
        private const int LVIF_TEXT = 0x0001;
        private const int LVM_SETITEM = 0x1006;
        private const uint PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (uint)(0x000F0000L | 0x00100000L | 0xFFF);
        private const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
        private const uint MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000;
        private const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpwdProcessID);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, uint dwFreeType);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, ref LV_ITEM buffer, int dwSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LV_ITEM
        {
            public uint mask;
            public int iItem;
            public int iSubItem;
            public uint state;
            public uint stateMask;
            public IntPtr pszText;
            public int cchTextMax;
            public int iImage;
        }

        public static string ReadListViewItem(IntPtr hWnd, int item)
        {
            const int dwBufferSize = 1024;

            int dwProcessID;
            LV_ITEM lvItem;
            string retval;
            bool bSuccess;
            IntPtr hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr lpRemoteBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr lpLocalBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr threadId = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                lvItem = new LV_ITEM();
                lpLocalBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dwBufferSize);
                // Get the process id owning the window
                threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out dwProcessID);
                if ((threadId == IntPtr.Zero) || (dwProcessID == 0))
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hWnd");

                // Open the process with all access
                hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, dwProcessID);
                if (hProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to access process");

                // Allocate a buffer in the remote process
                lpRemoteBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, dwBufferSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
                if (lpRemoteBuffer == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new SystemException("Failed to allocate memory in remote process");

                // Fill in the LVITEM struct, this is in your own process
                // Set the pszText member to somewhere in the remote buffer,
                // For the example I used the address imediately following the LVITEM stuct
                lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
                lvItem.iItem = item;
                lvItem.pszText = (IntPtr)(lpRemoteBuffer.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LV_ITEM)));
                lvItem.cchTextMax = 50;

                // Copy the local LVITEM to the remote buffer
                bSuccess = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpRemoteBuffer, ref lvItem, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LV_ITEM)), IntPtr.Zero);
                if (!bSuccess)
                    throw new SystemException("Failed to write to process memory");

                // Send the message to the remote window with the address of the remote buffer
                SendMessage(hWnd, LVM_GETITEM, 0, lpRemoteBuffer);

                // Read the struct back from the remote process into local buffer
                bSuccess = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpRemoteBuffer, lpLocalBuffer, dwBufferSize, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (!bSuccess)
                    throw new SystemException("Failed to read from process memory");

                // At this point the lpLocalBuffer contains the returned LV_ITEM structure
                // the next line extracts the text from the buffer into a managed string
                retval = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto((IntPtr (lpLocalBuffer.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LV_ITEM))));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lpLocalBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpLocalBuffer);
                if (lpRemoteBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
                    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpRemoteBuffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
                if (hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
            return retval;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWnd = FindWindow(null, "Windows Task Manager");
            var childWnd = FindWindowEx(mainWnd, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Processes");

            IntPtr count = SendMessage(mainWnd, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            Console.WriteLine(count);

            Console.WriteLine(ReadListViewItem(mainWnd, 1));
        }
    }
```

Please, somebody gives me suggestion!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng: Thank you for comment but that's not what I need. I'm looking for getting listview content from a windows application which is not started by myself (e.g. Windows Task Manager). Thanks anyway.